# Getting an input with a java applet while executing a method

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have implemented a console calculator application. It stores variables as well. Now I want to use the same parser in a java applet. I want to use the same Parser class but this time I want to get the inputs for variables via a dialog box. It should stop the execution of the program and asks for a user input in a popup box and when I enter the value, I want to use that value in the next line of the application.

instead of getting the value from bufferedreader, i want to do sthg like this

if someappletclasss.dialogresult = ok, 
value = someappletclass.myvalue;

I'm new to java programming and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more context will be very helpful.

Comment: "Getting an input with a java applet.."  My advice is to avoid applets until you gain more experience.  They are harder to develop and deploy than other (JFrame based) applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JOptionPane#showInputDialog()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

```
String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - How to make dialogs?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)